# R split dataframe at specific marker

Tags: r

I would like to make a script that reads in a txt file and splits it at specific points. The text file look like this:

```
>>PARAM:EDGER

a   10
b   10
c   30

>>PARAM:GSEA

d   10
e   10
f   30

>>PARAM:GO

g   2
h   3

>>PARAM:KEGG

i   9
j   20
```

The values are tab delimited.

I read in the file with `data <- read.table("config_2_R.txt",header=FALSE, sep="\t",fill = TRUE)`

I would like to split the data at >>PARAM:. For example:

```
df1
v1  v2
a   10
b   10
c   30

df2
v1  v2
d   10
e   10
f   30

df3
v1  v2
g   2
h   3

df4
v1  v2
i   9
j   20
```

How can I make it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all the data in at once, then find the ">>" pattern to split the data up, then read each chunk as a data.frame. For example

```
lines <- readLines("config_2_R.txt")
dfs <- lapply(split(lines, cumsum(grepl(">>", lines))), function(x) {
  read.table(text=x[-(1:2)])
})
```

This will return a list of data.frames which is usually easier to work with than a bunch of different variables in your global environment. But if you really need different variables, you can use

```
list2env(setNames(dfs, paste0("df", seq_along(dfs))), env=globalenv())
```

Or if you wanted to read them all into one data.frame but add a column so indicate what the PARAM: value was, you could do

```
lines <- readLines("config_2_R.txt")
dfs <- lapply(split(lines, cumsum(grepl(">>", lines))), function(x) {
  source <- gsub(">>PARAM:","", x[1])
  cbind(read.table(text=x[-(1:2)]), source)
})
do.call("rbind", dfs)
```